# What does eigenvalues of the Lorentz matrix represent physically speaking?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

In special relativity, if we have a boozt in the x - direction, the relationship between the coordinates of the inertial frame of reference S, and the one of S' (moving with velocity v relative to S), can be related as follows:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
x \\ t
\end{pmatrix} = \gamma(v)\begin{pmatrix}
1 & v \\
v/c^2 &  1\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x' \\ t'
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, mathematically speaking, we know that the eigenvalues correspond to some eigenvectors which in turn represents the vectors who stay parallell to their original direction. In this case, meaning for special relativity and the matrix given above, I wonder what this would represent? Would the eigenvectors of this transformation represent the "paths" in S and S' for which both observers agree on both it's position and time? I can understand that the eigenvectors must contain the vectors that are represented as (x, ct), as the speed of light must be same in both inertial frame of references.

Comment: I believe that should be $v/c^2$ in the transformation matrix if you're using units where $c \neq 1$.  (Also, why are you using units where $c \neq 1$?  It just makes your life more difficult.)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the eigenvalues of the Lorentz matrix?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108520/)

Comment: Regarding my previous comment (and vote), while the title of the question does not ask about the physical significance of the eigenvalues/eigenvectors, the body of the question does (and the question has been well-received).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you actually calculate the eigenvectors of this transformation you get the eigenvectors $(-1, 1)$ and $(1,1)$ (in units where $c = 1$.)  This corresponds to the fact that the null directions are invariant under Lorentz transformations.

Moreover, the corresponding eigenvalues are
$$
\sqrt{ \frac{1 - v}{1+v}}, \sqrt{\frac{1+v}{1-v}}
$$
respectively.  These can be recognized as the relativistic Doppler shift factors;  in other words, a photon with a null four-momentum will have its energy (and momentum) red- or blue-shifted by one of these factors under a boost, while its four-momentum continues to "point in the same direction" in spacetime.